# Is there way, how to change column to link-to-item in SharePoint online?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer

I have a problem. I need to change custom column (e.g. "serial number" type: number) to link-to-item column (as the "Title" column is).
I've used several tutorials almoust with the same answer. Add scope `LinkToItem="TRUE"` like this `<FieldRef Name="fieldName" LinkToItem="TRUE"/>`. 
But it isn't work. I've tried to change first letter to lower case as was recommended. But still not work.

In few tutorials was written that's recommended to wait for a moment.

Have anybody experience with this?? Thanx

Answer (score 0):

Open SharePoint designer to update filed of the list view(classic view).

```
<XmlDefinition>
<View Name="{E6EEC201-F041-4B16-B500-641ECBABD796}" DefaultView="TRUE" MobileView="TRUE" MobileDefaultView="TRUE" Type="HTML" DisplayName="All Items" Url="/sites/Developer/Lists/Details/AllItems.aspx" Level="1" BaseViewID="1" ContentTypeID="0x" ImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/generic.png?rev=45" ><Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="ID"/></OrderBy></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="LinkTitle"/><FieldRef Name="EmpNo"/><FieldRef Name="Phone"/><FieldRef Name="Software_x0020_version"/><FieldRef Name="Serial_x0020_Number" ListItemMenu="TRUE" LinkToItem="TRUE"/></ViewFields><RowLimit Paged="TRUE">30</RowLimit><JSLink>clienttemplates.js</JSLink><XslLink Default="TRUE">main.xsl</XslLink><CustomFormatter/><Toolbar Type="Standard"/></View></XmlDefinition>
</WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank, but this is for classic view as I suppose? I need it for modern view, especially for document library.